# How to delete just ONE post associated with a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When clicking the 'Delete Post' link in the all.html.erb view, all posts associated with a specific user are being deleted. To clarify, if I'm logged in and I attempt to delete a single one of my posts, all of my posts are deleted.

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to '/'
    flash[:alert] = 'Post was deleted.'
end
```

**Link in view:**

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <center><h3>Recent Posts</h3></center>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><%= post.title %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= post.content %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                By: <%= link_to User.find(post.user_id).name, profile_path(User.find(post.user_id).name) %>
                <% if session[:user_id] == post.user_id %>
                | <%= link_to 'Delete Post', deletepost_path(post.id), method: :delete %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>    
    <% end %>    
</div>
```

**Routes.rb if relevant:**

```
 get 'newpost', to: 'posts#new', as: 'newpost'
 post 'newpost', to: 'posts#create'
 delete 'deletepost/:id', to: 'posts#destroy', as: 'deletepost'
```

Comment: how do you load @posts?

Comment: @Gaston `@posts = Post.all.limit(10).order('created_at DESC')`

Comment: could you add 'byebug' after '@post' = Post.find(params[:id]). Click on delete and in the console write '@post?' To see the '@post's' content

Comment: @Gaston `(byebug) @post
#<Post id: 1, created_at: "2016-11-28 17:47:47", updated_at: "2016-11-28 17:47:47", title: "posty", content: "post", user_id: 1>`

Comment: so @post.destroy only destroys post id:1, how do you know that all the posts are being deleted?

Comment: @Gaston 1. They don't show up in the view after the redirect. 2. Entering Post.all in the console shows that they were deleted.

Comment: @Gaston Thank you for the help. Ended up remembering that I set the user_id as the primary key in the Post model.